# Searching on Google for mydomain, my domain name is shown as the page title instead of the actual page title

Tags: seo, google-search

When I search for my domain on Google, eg: `mydomain.com`, my site shows up with a title like "MyDomain" instead of that page's actual title.

Any clues on why this happens and how to fix it?

Edit:

This is the code from head:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Συγκριση τιμών - Τιμές προϊόντων,Αναζήτηση και προσφορές</title>
            <link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/105294720755057253319"/>
    <link href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/105294720755057253319?rel=author"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.seekit.gr/template_new/stylesheet/960.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.seekit.gr/template_new/stylesheet/screen.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.seekit.gr/template_new/stylesheet/color.css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.seekit.gr/template_new/stylesheet/ie.css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.seekit.gr/template_new/js/basket.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<script>
 var current_url = 'http://www.seekit.gr/';
 var module_title= 'index';
        </script>
    <link title="Seekit.gr - προσφορές" rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.seekit.gr/favicon.png" />
            </head>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Google](https://plus.google.com/+PierreFar/posts/62V16LPwzKv):

- Our algorithms generate thee alternative titles so that your page is no longer constrained with having just the one title for all the different queries your page ranks for. This has the nice side effect of making the result look more relevant to our searchers and...
- On average, the alternative titles increase the clickthrough rate on the results, i.e. more traffic for you.
- The  tag is still a primary source for titles we show so all our advice about make them concise and useful and enticing still very much apply. Keep an eye on the HTML Suggestions page in the Diagnostics section in Webmaster Tools for title suggestions.

See also: [Better page titles in search results](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/01/better-page-titles-in-search-results.html)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this blog post!!! Thanks for sharing. But i still find my site's title better looking than the one Google shows :D

Comment: Damnit, I've read that post and it didn't even occur to me... *slaps self* :)

Comment: Just FYI ya'll, it also does this sometimes for content too. You will see dynamic snippets based on query, much of the time ignoring your meta/rdf desc completely in lieu of better fitting content in page.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `<title></title>` tag with some content, on your page? You need to give some more information. Post the code of your site from `<head>` to `</head>`

It could also be that Google doesn't see much value in your Title-text, and chooses to show the URL since that is what was searched for.

***Edit:***
After testing, I see that the title is in fact displaying when searching for all sites within seekit.gr (site:seekit.gr). When searching for just the domain though, Google chooses to put only the Site Name (SeekIt). I believe this is because the contents of your `<title></title>` doesn't work in the UTF-8 charset. Here are two links to more information on this:

- http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768
- http://www.wizcity.com/Computers/Characters/GreekUTF8.php

[image: My search for seekit.gr]

Comment: There is a title tag on the page and in general my site is pretty good with it's tags. No extgra h1s or hidden text and stuff like these...

Comment: I am unable to re-produce the results you claim, when I myself search for "seekit.gr", or even when I search for "site:seekit.gr". It's difficult to diagnose the issue when you can't see it :-/. I see the title just fine.

Comment: You see the title? On which Google domain? Thanks for testing it.

Comment: I've appended my answer with my take on this

Answer (score 0):

If the title is there then you probably have recently changed your title from mydomain.
Google takes some time to update the new title of website probability a week or more.

Comment: I never changed the title to the domain. The site is up since february 2013 and till now it still shows the domain instead of the title.

Comment: I have checked your website. When I search using your current title in Google it gives the perfect result.

It has happened with my product page. My developer published my page with product name as the site title and it last for about 6 months. Whenever I search with the old title Google gives me the website with same old title and when I go the new title or any other search queries it gives me current title.

Nothing wrong with your site it’s just the Google data centers which it not update, It has created a document with your old site title and give it whenever you search with old title.